# dynamic programming for buying strategy

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say there are `s_1,s_2,...,s_n` apple sellers, depending on the amount that we buy, the price will be different, and price of buying i apples from seller j is p(i, j). What is the strategy for finding a way to buy exactly A apples (`0 <= A <= kn`) with minimum cost? I think a M*n table is needed to be built for developing dynamic programming algorithm, but am not sure how to design it. Moreover, I think time complexity should be O(n^2 k^2) something, am I correct?

Follow-up question: if we buy `u` apples from seller j, we are not allowed to buy `u+2` or more apples from its neighbors(`s_j-1` and `s_j+1`), how should we design the algorithm in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]. At this point, this seems more like a math question than a programming question. If you can figure out how to do this on paper, chances are you can figure out how to code it, later.

Comment: Thanks @jpaugh I think it's more an algorithm problem and I am not able to figure it out, I have been stuck in it for several hours...

Comment: How many different p(i,j) are there? The usual approach would be to determine the price to buy k apples from suppliers 1..n by finding the min of buying x apples from n and the rest at the best price from suppliers 1..n-1, with x being each of the different pricing-steps from p.

Comment: In fact, this reduces to _exactly_ the knapsack problem if you replace the different "tariffs" to buy one or more apples from a given supplier with different suppliers having different prices (and the number of apples being bought in bulk being the "weight" in the knapsack metaphor)

Comment: p(i,j) for all possibilities, which means, i's value is from 1 to n, j is from 1 to A

Comment: Hm, then this would transform the `i` sellers into `i*A` Knapsack-items, giving a complexity of O(nA²)... This might be a problem.

Comment: @jpaugh It is a bog standard dynamic programming problem.  Which is common in CS courses, and is generally not encountered in any math course.

Comment: @btilly Well, all of programming is technically mathematics; it's a fine line that has to be drawn somewhere. I just have not seen many questions of this nature which have been upvoted. If you believe it's worth answering, perhaps you should upvote the question. ;-)

Comment: @jpaugh I follow the algorithm tag.  This type of question is common there, as are people like you who think it isn't a programming problem.  But google the phrase "dynamic programming" and you see that it really is programming.

Comment: @Btilly I see. There are few tags where not having existing code is (easily) accepted. I'll take note of the distinction for [tag:algorithm]. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: About that second part: If we buy n apples from vendor j, are we allowed to buy 0 apples from vendors j+1 or j-1? I.e. is buying nothing an exception from that rule?

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for comment. Yes you can, if we buy n apples from vendor j, the amount of apple we can buy from its neighborhood should in the interval [j-2, j+2], or nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem nicely translates to the common Knapsack problem, except that you have many different "prices" and "weights" for each "item" to account for, i.e. your `p(i,j)` function.

The standard DP algorithm, shamelessly copied from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem), looks like this:

```
// Input:
// Values (stored in array v)     -> represented by p function
// Weights (stored in array w)    -> determined by parameter to p
// Number of distinct items (n)   -> different apple suppliers
// Knapsack capacity (W)          -> desired number of apples A

for j from 0 to W do:
    m[0, j] := 0

for i from 1 to n do:
    for j from 0 to W do:
        if w[i] > j then:
            m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
        else:
            m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
```

There are a few differences, though:

- you are not looking for the `max` value, but for the `min` price
- you can not buy *up to* `W` apples, but *exactly* `W` apples (otherwise, the best strategy would be not to buy any apples)
- consequently, there is no zeros-row; instead, your first row contains all the apples bought from supplier 1 at the corresponding bulk prices
- you have to account for the different values for `p(i, j)`

Thus, you can adapt the algorithm to something like this (using a Python-like list comprehension notation)

```
for j from 0 to W do:      // apples to buy from seller 1
    m[1, j] := p(1, j)

for i from 2 to n do:      // loop sellers 2 to n
    for j from 0 to W do:  // loop total number of apples to buy
        m[i, j] := min(m[i-1, j-k] + p(k, i) 
                       for k from 0 to j)  // apples bought from seller i
```

This means that you have three nested loops, though, giving this a complexity of O(nA²).

---

The 2nd part is a bit tricky, and I'm not sure I really understood it. Basically, this means that for each seller (except the first) you can only buy one more, the same number, or one less than from the previous seller. For this you'd have to extend the DP matrix to have a third dimension, the number of apples bought from that seller, and replace the `min` expression with an actual loop, assigning to different cells of that table.

Comment: Hi @tobias_k thanks for your answer, it is very impressing! I am thinking the time complexity could be `O(n*k*A)`, because, we should build a `n*k` table first, and then go through every entry will cost us `n*k`, and then for each entry, I think the complexity will be A for looking back on the table and seeking all possible combinations for this entry, correct me if I am mistaken. Furthermore, do you have any thought for problem 2? Thanks

Comment: Are you suggesting we buy from every seller? It would be easy to make an example where excluding a seller would yield a better price.

Comment: @גלעדברקן No, the range for quantity `k` goes from `0` to `j` for each seller. You can skip sellers (ignoring part 2), but the total has to be exactly `A`.

Comment: From question: `p(i, j)` is price for "i apples from seller j ." It looks to me that when you call `p`, `i` is never 0.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Good catch. It should be `p(k, i)` then. I just kept the loop variables from the original algorithm without noticing the inverted meaning. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure that you need for problem 1 is, for each `j` in `1..n` and `k` in `0..A`, the minimum amount you can have spent to buy `k` apples from the first `j` vendors, along with how many you bought from the last one.  Calculating that for a single vendor, given that you have it for the last, requires `O(A)` operations for each of `O(A) counts.  Do that for`n`vendors and you need`O(A^2*n)`time.  With some cleverness, you can also make it`O(A^2)` memory.

For problem 2 it becomes more tricky.  Instead of a data structure per number of apples bought through vendor `j`, it has to be a data structure per `(j, k)` because it matters how many apples you buy.  That makes it `O(A^3*n)` time.  (Actually better than that, because you never buy too many apples from any one vendor.)

Comment: Thanks @btilly for the second problem I am thinking if it has same time complexity as problem 1, and it can be solved by simply adding a `if` condition based on the first problem. Like based on the n*k table we have built in the first question like solving a knapsack problem, while doing the search for each entry, we skip those numbers that we don't want. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @user8142520 My thinking is that you can never go over `O(sqrt(A))` purchased from any one vendor.  So two of those apparent `O(A)` factors are actually `O(sqrt(A))` and the complexity does wind up the same.  I haven't tried to prove that, but it is what I think happens.